# How to deploy uaa as a war file in apache tomcat 8?

Tags: java, apache, maven, tomcat

I want to deploy uaa in tomcat 8.

I have created a war file and placed it at this location `C:\Softwares\apache-tomcat-8.5.5\webapps\cloudfoundry-identity-uaa-3.6.0.war`. My tomcat is getting started but when m trying to open UAA login page 
`http://localhost:8080/uaa/login`, I'm getting the following error:

`HTTP Status 404 - /uaa/login`.

Please tell me whether I am doing it correctly or not, if not please suggest a way.

Comment: check the logs in tomcat/log to see if there is any exception

Comment: [2016-09-15 13:16:46.141] cloudfoundry-identity-server/cloudfoundry-identity-uaa-3.6.0 - ???? [ZoneAwareMetadataManager.Refresh[idpMetadataManager]] .... DEBUG --- ZoneAwareIdpMetadataManager: Running SAML SP refresh[ZoneAwareMetadataManager.Refresh[idpMetadataManager]-803285994] - ignoreTimestamp=false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 copy your war to webapp directiory

2 rename your war to ROOT.war

3 make sure your tomcat/conf/server.xml is like:

`<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">`

4 start the server

`bin/startup.sh`

Answer (score 1):

By default, the context root for the web app in Tomcat will be the war file's name, which in this case is `cloudfoundry-identity-uaa-3.6.0`. So, try going to the URL at `http://localhost:8080/cloudfoundry-identity-uaa-3.6.0/login`. You can change the default context path in the Tomcat Manager app.